# Combine Array and String in Mapping in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui

I need to combine `rows` and `rows2`. If either of them don't have a value, their values is "none". How do I combine them? The problem now is that its creating multiple rows that is empty.

Codesandbox [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictable-material-demo-forked-lzpud?file=/demo.js)

```
    <TableBody>
      {[...(rows || []), ...(rows2 || [])].map((row) => (
        <TableRow
          key={row.name}
          sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
        >
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
            {row.name}
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
          <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </TableBody>
```

Comment: Well, what does `const a = "none"; console.log(...a)` print?

Comment: @windowsill The same as `console.log("n", "o", "n", "e")`

Comment: Hey Joseph, will `rows2` always be a string? You are spreading the string in as a character array. Can you clarify what you want to "combine"? From what I can tell you are are iterating one and then iterating the other. Is that all you want to do, or do you want to "merge" any of the row data? Can you provide an example expected output?

Comment: @DrewReese. No `rows` and `rows2` will not always be a string. If they have a value they will return to an array, if they don't have a value, they will return to a string "none". I want to combine `rows` and `rows2` to iterate them into the table. `rows` and `rows2` have the same data structure.

Comment: @DrewReese. When `rows` have values while `rows` return "none", then only iterate `rows` in the table and vice versa. If both have values of "none", then don't iterate them in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are spreading the string value "none" into a character array and then mapping this to rows. This results in four empty rows corresponding to `["n", "o", "n", "e"]`.

Assuming you just want to combine the two "array" values that are possibly sometimes a string, and only render the rows that actually have row data, copy the `rows` and `rows2` values into the array (*not spread*), run the array through a filter function to ensure only array type values are passed through, flatten the array of arrays down to a single array, and then map.

```
{[rows, rows2]
  .filter(Array.isArray)
  .flat()
  .map((row) => (
    <TableRow
      key={row.name}
      sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
    >
      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
        {row.name}
      </TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
      <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
```

[image: Edit combine-array-and-string-in-mapping-in-react]

Comment: Thank you. How can you make the background color of `rows` the `fat` column to green for example?

Comment: @Joseph You can create a styled component, see updated sandbox link. I just borrowed from one of the table examples in the docs, but you can get much fancier with the styling.

Comment: Thanks Drew. but I would  like to apply  only to the body and also for the `rows` not `rows2` if `rows2` have a data

Comment: @Joseph You don't need to specify any styling for the `tableCellClasses.head` head class if you don't want to. So you are only wanting to style the cells if the data is from the `rows` array?

Comment: Yes if coming from `rows` array only.

Comment: @Joseph I see. Since you say `rows` and `rows2` have the same data structure you'll likely need to inject a new property into the `rows` array elements to identify them while mapping. You can then pass this as a prop into the styled cell and conditionally apply style. See this [codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/combine-array-and-string-in-mapping-in-react-forked-sptxr?file=/demo.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the syntax for `result` below. Just replace the map callback function with whatever you want:

```js
const rows = [
  {
    name: "frozen yogurt",
    calories: 22,
    fat: 33,
    carbs: 44,
    protein: 44
  },
  // ...
];

const rows2 = "none";

const result = [...(Array.isArray(rows) ? rows : []), ...(Array.isArray(rows2) ? rows2 : [])]
  .map(row => /* whatever you want here, but I'll use */ row);

console.log(result);
```

Or you can make a function and re-use it:

```js
function arrayValueOrEmptyArray (value) {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? value : [];
}

const rows = [
  {
    name: "frozen yogurt",
    calories: 22,
    fat: 33,
    carbs: 44,
    protein: 44
  },
  // ...
];

const rows2 = "none";

const result = [...arrayValueOrEmptyArray(rows), ...arrayValueOrEmptyArray(rows2)].map(row => row);

console.log(result);
```